# How to delete a column out of a pandas pivot table? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
In  [31]: df.pivot(index='orderid', columns='C', values='productid')
Out [31]: 
       C        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ... 71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
orderid                                                                                 
20000765    624380  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
20000766    624380  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
20000768    1305984 1305985 1305983 1306021 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

I would like to delete the first column. However, when I do that the table unpivots again.

What I can I do to delete the "C" / "Orderid" column and the numbers underneath it?

Comment: what does `df.pivot(index='orderid', columns='C', values='productid').drop('C', axis=1)` output?

Comment: @luigigi `KeyError: "['C'] not found in axis"`

Comment: and how about `df.pivot(index='orderid', columns='C', values='productid').reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: That replaced the first column with an index, which looks much better. Not sure if I can use it for further analysis, but I'll try and keep this post up-to-date.

Comment: well, your "first column" was your index. you need any index in your dataframe

Comment: Ah, yeah I see now. Thanks! I'm very new to Python, so still learning a lot.